# How to make gradle use the cached dependencies for all android studio projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android studio version 3.0.1 in ubuntu 16.04.2 and I need gradle to always use the cached version of the dependencies for every android app I try to build. I live in Ethiopia and I do not get internet access as much I would like to.

Answer (score 0):

After you successfully build the project. You can tell Android Studio to use cache dependencies from menu:

File **->** Settings **->** Build, Execution, Deployment **->** Gradle **->** Global Gradle Settings. You need to check `offline work` options. Like the following image:

[image]

Every other project using the same dependencies will work without needing to connect to the internet.

Comment: yea bro, tried it it doesn't work...for e.g it will not use the cached junit testing framework for another app I want to develop

Answer (score 0):

after all this time, I found a workaround. It is not elegant, but it was enough for me and should anybody else be troubled by this here is what I did. I downloaded the library I wanted to use (in my case it was junit) as a jar file and I dragged and dropped it on to the libs folder of my android studio project and finally I added "compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')" to the build.gradle file and it worked. I don't know if it will sustain but currently it solved my problem.